# Alternative for INNER JOIN with no cartesian product

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to optimize this query by avoiding inner joins?
I think the inner joins makes it very slow.

```
SELECT CitiBikeTrips2.start_time, 
       CitiBikeTrips2.stop_time, 
       CitiBikeTrips2.trip_duration, 
       CitiBikeTrips2.start_station_id, 
       nearestmeasurementbike.o3_measurement, 
       o3_measurement.data 
FROM   bikestations 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT citibiketrips.start_time, 
                          citibiketrips.stop_time, 
                          citibiketrips.trip_duration, 
                          citibiketrips.start_station_id 
                   FROM   citibiketrips 
                   WHERE  citibiketrips.start_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' 
                     AND citibiketrips.start_time <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00' 
                  ) CitiBikeTrips2 
               ON CitiBikeTrips2.start_station_id = bikestations.bikestationid 
       INNER JOIN nearestmeasurementbike 
               ON nearestmeasurementbike.bikestationid = CitiBikeTrips2.start_station_id 
       INNER JOIN o3_measurement 
               ON o3_measurement.mstationid = nearestmeasurementbike.o3_measurement 
              AND Date(o3_measurement.m_time) = Date(CitiBikeTrips2.start_time) 
              AND Hour(o3_measurement.m_time) = Hour(CitiBikeTrips2.start_time)
```

Edit 1:

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,taxi_trip,NULL,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,112789716,100.00,"Using where"
1,SIMPLE,TaxiZones,NULL,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,test_schema.taxi_trip.pulocationdid,1,100.00,NULL
1,SIMPLE,NearestMeasurementTaxi,NULL,ref,"TaxiStationId,O3_measurement",TaxiStationId,5,test_schema.taxi_trip.pulocationdid,1,100.00,"Using where"
1,SIMPLE,O3_measurement,NULL,ref,"PRIMARY,index2",PRIMARY,4,test_schema.NearestMeasurementTaxi.O3_measurement,8718,100.00,"Using where"
```

Edit 2:
These are DDL for the tables

```
citibiketrips | CREATE TABLE `citibiketrips` (
  `trip_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Trip_Duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Start_Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stop_Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Start_Station_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `End_Station_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Bike_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `User_Type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Birth_Year` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`trip_id`),
  KEY `date2IndexBikes` (`Start_Station_Id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `end` (`End_Station_Id`),
  KEY `index4` (`trip_id`,`Trip_Duration`),
  KEY `start_Time_index` (`Start_Time`),
  CONSTRAINT `citibiketrips_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Start_Station_Id`) REFERENCES `bikestations` (`BikeStationId`),
  CONSTRAINT `citibiketrips_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Start_Station_Id`) REFERENCES `bikestations` (`BikeStationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17150456 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

  BikeStations | CREATE TABLE `BikeStations` (
  `BikeStationId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `BikeStationName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BikeStationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

O3_measurement | CREATE TABLE `O3_measurement` (
  `MStationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `M_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Data` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MStationID`,`M_time`),
  KEY `index2` (`MStationID`),
  KEY `mTime_index` (`M_time`),
  CONSTRAINT `O3MStation` FOREIGN KEY (`MStationID`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

 NearestMeasurementBike | CREATE TABLE `NearestMeasurementBike` (
  `BikeStationId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `O3_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PM25C_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOx_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NO_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NO2_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BP_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SO2_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temp_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WS_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WD_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NO23_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Precipitation_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Methane_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trace_CO_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RS_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RD_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PM25FEM_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Non_methane_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total_hc_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SO2T_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SO23_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PM25R_measurement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `BikeStationId` (`BikeStationId`),
  KEY `O3_measurement` (`O3_measurement`),
  KEY `PM25C_measurement` (`PM25C_measurement`),
  KEY `NOx_measurement` (`NOx_measurement`),
  KEY `NO_measurement` (`NO_measurement`),
  KEY `NO2_measurement` (`NO2_measurement`),
  KEY `BP_measurement` (`BP_measurement`),
  KEY `SO2_measurement` (`SO2_measurement`),
  KEY `CO_measurement` (`CO_measurement`),
  KEY `Temp_measurement` (`Temp_measurement`),
  KEY `WS_measurement` (`WS_measurement`),
  KEY `WD_measurement` (`WD_measurement`),
  KEY `NO23_measurement` (`NO23_measurement`),
  KEY `Precipitation_measurement` (`Precipitation_measurement`),
  KEY `Methane_measurement` (`Methane_measurement`),
  KEY `Trace_CO_measurement` (`Trace_CO_measurement`),
  KEY `RS_measurement` (`RS_measurement`),
  KEY `RD_measurement` (`RD_measurement`),
  KEY `PM25FEM_measurement` (`PM25FEM_measurement`),
  KEY `Non_methane_measurement` (`Non_methane_measurement`),
  KEY `Total_hc_measurement` (`Total_hc_measurement`),
  KEY `SO2T_measurement` (`SO2T_measurement`),
  KEY `SO23_measurement` (`SO23_measurement`),
  KEY `PM25R_measurement` (`PM25R_measurement`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BikeStationId`) REFERENCES `bikestations` (`BikeStationId`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`Temp_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`WS_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_12` FOREIGN KEY (`WD_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_13` FOREIGN KEY (`NO23_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_14` FOREIGN KEY (`Precipitation_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_15` FOREIGN KEY (`Methane_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_16` FOREIGN KEY (`Trace_CO_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_17` FOREIGN KEY (`RS_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_18` FOREIGN KEY (`RD_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_19` FOREIGN KEY (`PM25FEM_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`O3_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_20` FOREIGN KEY (`Non_methane_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_21` FOREIGN KEY (`Total_hc_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_22` FOREIGN KEY (`SO2T_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_23` FOREIGN KEY (`SO23_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_24` FOREIGN KEY (`PM25R_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`PM25C_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`NOx_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`NO_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`NO2_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`BP_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`SO2_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nearestmeasurementbike_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`CO_measurement`) REFERENCES `monitoring_station` (`MStationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

This is how my result looks

```
Start_Time,Stop_Time,Start_Station_Id,Data,MStationID,Latitude,Longitude
"2017-01-12 09:03:16","2017-01-12 09:17:17",161,0.007,2,40.75802813531073,-73.97769809775781
"2017-01-12 09:03:17","2017-01-12 09:27:28",230,0.007,2,40.75981760723498,-73.98419647105034
"2017-01-12 09:03:17","2017-01-12 09:41:12",50,0.007,2,40.76623760315835,-73.99513499940588
```

Edit 3:
I added Indexes with the help of workbench to the following columns:

- CitiBikeTrips.TripID.
- CitiBikeTrips.Start_Time.
- O3_measurement.M_time
- O3_measurement.MStationID

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A secure way yo know if your query Is slow by joins Is apply EXPLAIN ay the beginning of the dame query, do It an update with those details your question

Comment: INNER JOINs don’t make your query slow - bad or missing INDEXes (or outdated STATISTICS objects) do!

Comment: Show output of `show create table tablename` for all 4 tables, explain what the query is supposed to do, and show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: If your query has not index over any column then It maybe Is making a full scan of your table data giving as result a poor performance  consider edit and add more info

Comment: How many rows are you working with?  The JOINs aren't your problem. The problem is likely in you indexes, the subquery, and the `date()` and `hour()` functions in your JOINs.

Comment: I am working with ~17million rows Edit: i tried to run it without hour and date function but the performance did not increase

Comment: Try in a copy of your DB adding indexes about the columns @Shawn mentioned

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It takes ~30 seconds to fetch 10000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is build your query in smalls steps and during each step test the query time and check the explain to see if you are using index:

**Step A:** You only use bikestations for bikestationid. You dont need create a subquery, just do a direct JOIN. You have the right index for `start_station_id` and `start_time`

Also consider you should use `<` instead of `<=`

```
SELECT citibiketrips.start_time, 
       citibiketrips.stop_time, 
       citibiketrips.trip_duration,  
       citibiketrips.start_station_id 
FROM   citibiketrips 
JOIN   bikestations 
  ON   citibiketrips.start_station_id = bikestations.bikestationid 
WHERE  citibiketrips.start_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND  citibiketrips.start_time <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
```

**Step B:** Also have the index for `bikestationid` so should be quick

```
SELECT citibiketrips.start_time, 
       citibiketrips.stop_time, 
       citibiketrips.trip_duration,  
       citibiketrips.start_station_id 
FROM   citibiketrips 
JOIN   bikestations 
  ON   citibiketrips.start_station_id = bikestations.bikestationid 
JOIN nearestmeasurementbike 
  ON nearestmeasurementbike.bikestationid = citibiketrips.start_station_id 
WHERE  citibiketrips.start_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND  citibiketrips.start_time <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
```

**Step C:** Here is where you may have problems. Even when you have index on `mstationid` and `m_time` the moment you use a function like `DATE()` the engine cant use the index.

What you have to do in order to use index is create new fields update those from the original time and then create index for those fields. Now your query would looks like this:

```
SELECT citibiketrips.start_time, 
       citibiketrips.stop_time, 
       citibiketrips.trip_duration,  
       citibiketrips.start_station_id 
FROM   citibiketrips 
JOIN   bikestations 
  ON   citibiketrips.start_station_id = bikestations.bikestationid 
JOIN nearestmeasurementbike 
  ON nearestmeasurementbike.bikestationid = citibiketrips.start_station_id 
JOIN o3_measurement 
  ON o3_measurement.mstationid = nearestmeasurementbike.o3_measurement 
 AND o3_measurement.m_time_date = CitiBikeTrips2.start_time_date
 AND o3_measurement.m_time_hour = CitiBikeTrips2.start_time_hour
WHERE  citibiketrips.start_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND  citibiketrips.start_time <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
```